# href is not working in my nav menu bar list

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

i can seem to get the href links in the side nav bar working.i have a feeling it might have something to do with my css. i have been trying to fix this for the past 1 hour but i cant find where the problem is.

```
    <nav id="nav" style="display: block;
            z-index: 0;
           -webkit-transition: none;
            transition: none;
            transition-property: none;
            transition-duration: initial;
            transition-timing-function: initial;
            transition-delay: initial" class="active">

            <div id="arrow"></div>
            <ul id="nav-menu-items">
            <li class="menu-item dark" id="DMIT" onmouseover="changetext();"onMouseOut="Defaulttext();"><a href="dmit.html">Diploma in MIT</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="ECC" onmouseover="changetext1();" onMouseOut="Defaulttext1();"><a href="ECC.html">Diploma in ECC </a></li>
            <li class="menu-item dark" id="AAT" onmouseover="changetext2();" onMouseOut="Defaulttext2();" ><a href="AAT.html">Diploma in AAT</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="ME" onmouseover="changetext3();" onMouseOut="Defaulttext3();" ><a href="Me.html">Diploma in ME</a> </li>
            <li class="menu-item dark"  id="TMT" onmouseover="changetext4();" onMouseOut="Defaulttext4();"   ><a href="TMT.html">Diploma in TMT</a> </li>
             <li class="menu-item pink" id="nav-choose"><img src="images/global/tri.png">     <br>
            Choose A Course</li>
    </ul> 


 </ul>
  </nav>
```

this is my css code

```
#nav{
position: absolute;
top: 254px;
left: 320px;
cursor: pointer;
width: 118px;
z-index: 2;
-webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.6s;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
```

}

```
#nav-menu-items {
       position: relative;
}
#nav-menu-items .menu-item a {
       display: block;
       color: #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
       text-align: center;
       line-height: 10px;
       font-weight: 200;
       padding: 8px 0px 9px 0px;


}
#nav .menu-item a:hover{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(images/global/whitebox.jpg);
}
#nav .menu-item:hover{
    background-image: url(images/global/whitebox.jpg);
}
```

javascript code

```
  function changetext()
{
var id=document.getElementById("DMIT"); 
id.style.color="black";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in Multimedia & infocomm Technology ";


}
function Defaulttext()
{
var id=document.getElementById("DMIT"); 
id.style.color="white";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in MIT ";

}

//ecc hover

 function changetext1()
{
var id1=document.getElementById("ECC");
id1.style.color="black";
id1.style.textAlign="center";
id1.innerHTML="Diploma in Electronics, Computer & Communications ";
}
function Defaulttext1()
{

var id1=document.getElementById("ECC");
id1.style.color="white";
id1.style.textAlign="center";
id1.innerHTML="Diploma in ECC ";
}

//AAT hover
function changetext2()
{
var id=document.getElementById("AAT"); 
id.style.color="black";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in Aeronautical & Aerospace Technology";

}
function Defaulttext2()
{
var id=document.getElementById("AAT"); 
id.style.color="white";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in AAT ";

} 
function changetext3()
{
var id=document.getElementById("ME"); 
id.style.color="black";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in Mechatronics Engineering  ";

}
function Defaulttext3()
{
var id=document.getElementById("ME"); 
id.style.color="white";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in ME ";

} 
function changetext4()
{
var id=document.getElementById("TMT"); 
id.style.color="black";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in Telematics & Media Technology  ";

}
function Defaulttext4()
{
var id=document.getElementById("TMT"); 
id.style.color="white";
id.style.textAlign="center";
id.innerHTML="Diploma in TMT ";

}
```

Comment: you have given 0 z-index in your inline css over nav element try to make it bigger number may it helps? also what is in changetext( methods)?

Comment: what is not working? you mean links? if yes, check the jsfiddle. it is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/3LjAh/

Comment: what exactly is your problem with this code snippet?

Comment: i cant get href working in the li list.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your mouseover functions change the innerHTML of the li elements and replace the a elements inside them with simple text

Example:

You'll need to get the a element first (all children for the current element are available in the `children` object; beware of IE <=8, it will include comments nodes within `children`)

so, in the `changetext()` function you should add

```
var _link = id.children[0];
```

and instead of

```
id.innerHTML="Diploma in Multimedia & infocomm Technology ";
```

you should have

```
_link.innerHTML="Diploma in Multimedia & infocomm Technology ";
```

You'll need to make similiar changes to the `Defaulttext()` function (also the rest of the functions)

Comment: i dont get it. could you give me a example?

Answer (score -2):

Add this....

```
id.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "Diploma in TMT ";
```

You are removing the A tag when you rewrite the innerHTML

Comment: I can't comment yet... im a newb.

Comment: He can't add a comment maybe that's why he posted it here, but still doesn't change the fact that this is not a answer

Comment: sorry. not an answer.